# What is Jquery library can draw Link Graph

Tags: jquery, graph

I'm trying to draw Link Graph on a website.
I mean, draw a few circle, and when click on a circle, it will draw many new circle around like a star.

Example, in this picture
[image]

When click on yellow area, will create red circles around.

So I search about jquery libraries, but almost does not support Link Graph (high chart, flot...)

I found arbor.js can support to do it.

But do you know any other library?

Thank alot

Comment: Have you tried Googling it? There's should be something out there. E.g. http://arborjs.org/

Comment: Oh I searched and found it. 
I will update in my question
Can you list another library ?

Comment: Just search for "JavaScript graph library" Another example is http://sigmajs.org/

Comment: I didn't found it. Thank you for your support